# How to create a JSONObject of Objects? Android

Tags: java, android, json

I want to create a `JSONObject` like this:

```
[
   {
       id:01,
       name:"John",
       number:010
   },
   {
       id:02,
       name:"Mike",
       number: 020
   }
]
```

This is my code:

```
public void equipmentViewed(List<Equipment> equipmentSelected, final OnControlResponseListener listener, String description, Equipment equipment) throws JSONException {
        wsAccessControl = WSAccessControl.getInstance();

        EquipmentViewed equipmentViewed = new EquipmentViewed();
        equipmentViewed.setEquipment(equipmentsCount(equipmentSelected));

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

        try {
            jsonObject.put("", new JSONArray(equipmentViewed.getEquipment().toString()));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to create json object. Cause: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        String url = Constants.PROVIDER_DOMAIN_URL + Constants.REQUEST_EQUIPMENT;
        wsAccessControl.makeWSRequest(RequestType.POST, url, jsonObject, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                listener.OnResponseReceived(response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                listener.OnResponseError(error);
            }
        }, true);
    }
```

Where `EquipmentViewed` contains a `String` list equipment.

Comment: What String is returned from `equipmentViewed.getEquipment()` ? please share

Comment: it's a list of information, like, name, model, serialNumber, location

Answer (score 5):

You can create the JSON you want using this:

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject();
obj1.put("id", "01");
obj1.put("name", "John");
obj1.put("number", "010");

JSONObject obj2 = new JSONObject();
obj2.put("id", "02");
obj2.put("name", "Mike");
obj2.put("number", "020");

array.put(obj1);
array.put(obj2);

/* array = [
              {
                   id:01,
                   name:"John",
                   number:010
               },
               {
                   id:02,
                   name:"Mike",
                   number: 020
               }
           ]
  */
```

Comment: I used Gson, way easier. But Thank you anyway

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [JSONTokener](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONTokener.html) for this Task.

```
    try{
        String json = equipmentViewed.getEquipment().toString();
        JSONArray object = (JSONArray) new JSONTokener(json).nextValue();
        JSONObject firstEntry = (JSONObject) object.get(0);
        JSONObject sndEntry = (JSONObject) object.get(1);
    }catch (JSONException ex){
      //TODO handle Error here
    }
```

If your equipmentViewed.getEquipment().toString()returns the following:

```
   /* String json =
   [
       {
           id:01,
           name:"John",
           number:010
       },
       {
           id:02,
           name:"Mike",
           number: 020
       }
    ] */
```

Comment: but in this case something like this is created: { id: [ {  010; 020  } ] right?

Comment: sry I got your question wrong and edited the answer. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: I used Gson, way easier. But Thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this :

```
JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();
for (int i = 0; i < equipmentViewed.getEquipment().size(); i++) {
    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
    jsonObject.put("id", equipmentViewed.getEquipment().get(i).getId());
    jsonObject.put("name", equipmentViewed.getEquipment().get(i).getName());
    jsonObject.put("number", equipmentViewed.getEquipment().get(i).getNumber());
    jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
}
```

You will have all the data in your JsonArray object `jsonArray`.
I am assuming you the objects in your `equipmentViewed.getEquipment()` list have those getter methods.

All the best :)

Comment: I used Gson, way easier. But Thank you anyway